# Usando Ubuntu: No hay manera de cerrar las ventanas - Botón X perdido

Tags: ubuntu

Hola buenos días amigos

Estoy usando Ubuntu, ultima versión, tengo dos pantallas y uso la pequeña (laptop) como principal. En dicha pantalla cualquier programa o ventana de browser que abro, se expande hasta el punto donde los botones de la esquina superior-derecha, para cerrar - expàndir - minimizar quedan ocultos por el header del sistema operativo de ubuntu.

Por lo que al expandir una ventana sea broswer o software, se hace imposible de cerrar-minimizar.

Hay alguna solución práctica para que esto no ocurra más?

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda!
Gnzlo

Comment: Hola, esto es StackOverflow en Español, por favor traduce la pregunta para que te podamos ayudar. Gracias

Comment: Hecho JDev, siento la confusión xD Gracias a ti.